# .env variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, .env

Javascript says that my variables which are in .env are undefined. I've installed dotenv but it doesn't work.

My index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');



mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
dotenv.config();
mongoose
    .connect(
        process.env.MONGODB_URL
    )
    .then(() => console.log("Database is working"))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
app.use(express.json());
app.use('', authRoute);


app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
    console.log('Server is up on port ' + process.env.PORT)
})
```

My auth.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const Crypto = require('crypto-js');
const { response } = require('express');
const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
//  Create a registration
console.log(secretKey);

router.post('/rejestracja', async (req, res)=>{
    const nowyUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: Crypto.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY).toString(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        username: req.body.username,
    });
    try{
        const newedUser = await nowyUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(newedUser);
    }
    catch(err){res.status(500).json(err)};
})
 
// Create a login

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        }
        

        const securedPass = Crypto.AES.decrypt( user.password, "a");
        const password = securedPass.toString(Crypto.enc.Utf8);
        console.log(password);
        if (password !== req.body.password) {
            res.status(401).json("Email i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        }else {
            res.status(200).json(user);
        }
    } 
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
    }
    
});


module.exports = router
```

And my .env

```js
MONGODB_URL = mongodb+srv://someInterestingWords
PORT = 5500
SEC_KEY = a
```

Everything works when these variables are in my code, not in .env.
I've tried to delete dotenv and add it again but id doesn't change anything.
process.env.something works in index.js but it doesn't in other files

[My project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkirA.png)

Comment: Show your project file structure. Where is `.env` located

Comment: can you share your sorce code after you changed

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you doing `require`, Node.JS executing specified file (or importing lib).

Now let's look at first lines of Your code:

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
dotenv.config();
```

You may notice: first you doing `require` on `./routes/user` and `./routes/auth`, then you doing `dotenv.config()`.

You need to do `dotenv.config()` Before using `process.env`, so try next:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
/* 
   Doing `config` just after `require`.
   Also, in most cases, You don't need dotenv after using this once,
   so no need to store `dotenv` constant. 
*/
require("dotenv").config(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
// other lines...
```

Also notice, if `.env` file locates not in `__dirname` (directory, where launches main file), you need to specify it's location:

```js
require('dotenv').config({path: '../configs/.env'});
```

or using `path`:

```js
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '../configs/.env')});
```

Comment: I've put require("dotenv").config() between const port and const userRoute and it still doesn't work link to imgur https://imgur.com/a/7QckHKn

Comment: Yeah i made a mistake, `const port` is also using `process.env`...

But that's not looks like that was problem.
Could you please show full error you're catching? Did you tried to log `process.env.SEC_KEY` in `./routes/auth`?

Comment: Sorry again, I didn't seen you added your project file structure.

You need to use `.config({path: '../.env'})`

Comment: yep the udnifed log in console is a try of reading SEC_KEY in auth.js. Adding the path changed error to this https://imgur.com/a/On8p5Ai

Comment: Well try this:
```js
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env')});
console.log(Object.keys(process.env));
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'));
```

You'll see all env properties and full path to your .env file.

Comment: I @Drom Hour I can find it in this list but it still says that it's undefined https://imgur.com/a/A8M1Tqx

Comment: I've copied your project file structure and tested it by myself. It's working for me(

Maybe try `console.log(process.env)`?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zan8V.png